# How to display 2007 excel ribbons

Tags: excel, vba

I was looking for a vba method to hide al excel ribbons on file startup.

From this website I copied into my worksheet's "Thisworkbook" two subroutines that hide all ribbons upon file activation and show them again on file deactivation.

This worked.

However, I need to know how to get back to all my macros?
Every time I start the spreadsheet the ribbons are hidden by my vba code. How do I get to the ribbons and perform other editing on my workbook?

I have searched for a solution to no avail.

Comment: Maybe you should modify the code that hides "all" ribbons, so that it doesn't hide them all?  You indicate you have searched for a solution to no avail, but **what have you actually tried?**

Answer (score 0):

how to get back to all my macros?
You mean start VBA IDE?
Alt-F11 does it.